# Count the number for a variable in a month

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a frequency for each date, how do I total the sum of that frequency for each unique month?

Example:

Before:

```
 df <- data.frame(
   Date = c('2010-01-15','2010-01-25','2010-02-12','2010-03-15','2010-03-11','2011-01-12'),
   Freq = c(1,1,1,1,0,1)
 )
```

After:

```
 df_output = data.frame(
   Month = c(1,2,3,13),
   Total = c(2,1,1,1)
 )
```

Note: I do not want to sum the same month of different years together, I would like them to be treated as separate. Hence the month 13 in the example.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier option is to convert to year month and do a group by sum (if needed, can get the 'Month' by subtracting from the `first` 'year')

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    group_by(yearmon = as.yearmon(Date)) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(Freq)) %>%
    transmute(year = year(yearmon), 
        Month= 12 * (year - first(year)) + month(yearmon), n, year = NULL )
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Month     n
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2
#2     2     1
#3     3     1
#4    13     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(month=month(Date)) %>% group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(Total=sum(Freq))
```

Comment: This does not give the same answer as the one shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Convert `Date` to a `yearmon` class variable `ym`.  This class internally represents year/month as year + fraction where fraction = 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, ..., 11/12 for Dec.  Convert that to a `Month` number and use `xtabs` and `as.data.frame` to perform the aggregation and conversion to data frame.  This assumes that the month number of the first row is one and other rows are counted relative to that.  It should work whether or not the first row is a January.  This only uses the zoo package and is short.

```
library(zoo)

ym <- as.yearmon(df$Date)
Month <- round(12 * (ym - ym[1]) + 1
as.data.frame(xtabs(Freq ~ Month, df))
```

giving:

```
  Month Freq
1     1    2
2     2    1
3     3    1
4    13    1
```

**2)** A second approach is to create a zoo object `Freq` with a yearmon class time index aggregating at the same time.  Then replace the yearmon index with a month number and use `fortify.zoo` to convert it to a data frame (or possibly omit the last line and just leave it as a zoo series).

```
library(zoo)

Freq <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = sum)
time(Freq) <- round(12 * (time(Freq) - time(Freq)[1])) + 1
fortify.zoo(Freq, name = "Month")
```

giving:

```
  Month Freq
1     1    2
2     2    1
3     3    1
4    13    1
```